# custom JList Cell Renderer - Cell Selection?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listcellrenderer

Good day.
I'm pretty new to `CellRenderer` and stuff and I am still reading a lot about it. Right now, I'm stuck with something I'm not sure how to work. I was able to put a `JPanel` inside my `JList` by setting it's `CellRenderer` to a custom one. But here is the million dollar question: How can I interact with the controls?

I mean, I want to be able to right click into the cell that contains my `jPanel`,
Right click to show some actions, and Highlight the selected row.

How can I achieve this?

heres is my code:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class cellTest extends JPanel{
    JLabel label;

    public cellTest(){
        buildInterface();
    }

    private void buildInterface(){
        label = new JLabel();

        setLayout(new CardLayout());
        add(label);
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        String pre = "<html><body style='width: 200px;'>";
        label.setText(pre+text);
    }
}
```

Second Part:

```
    import Read.Medicine_Cell;
    import java.awt.CardLayout;
    import java.awt.Component;
    import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
    import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JList;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class testjava {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setSize(500, 500);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setLayout(new CardLayout());

        JList list = new JList();
        DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();

        dlm.addElement("This is a test");
        dlm.addElement("I wanna know if it works");
        dlm.addElement("Pardon if im not that good yet");
        dlm.addElement("or my problem is basic");

        list.setModel(dlm);
        list.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
        jf.add(new JScrollPane(list));
        jf.show();
    }
    static class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer{
        final cellTest cellx = new cellTest();
        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(final JList list, final Object value, final int index, final boolean isSelected, final boolean hasFocus){
            final String text = (String) value;
            cellx.setText(text);
            return cellx;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For interaction you must make a cell editor as well.

Comment: Renderer responsibilities: the selected cell gets isSelected true, the focused cell hasFocus so you can render the cell appropriately (background color).

Comment: is there by any change you have a good reference that about custom rendering or editing JList or jTable? I believe the two share almost the same trait right?

Comment: This task looks like it would be better suited to a `JTable`. The renderer of a list is only intended to render. Controls inside it are a 'view with no functionality'.

Comment: True, but I was thinking of allowing the user to check on the details of the item inside the list. This is a part of a small module that provides small information for quick viewing purposes. thats why I would like to have it working inside a jList. I guess I should just stick with ListArrays that contains the information based on the index of the jList.